# parallel computation of python snippet

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am failing to do parallel computation over each class category, is it possible to do below serial code and how I am trying to do parallel computation.

```
class_groups = {}
charts_list = ['Future Admission', 'Future Revenue Projection']

for classes in class_list:
    classes = int(classes)
    class_df = df_all[df_all['Class'] == classes]
    student_num = len(df_all['student_id'][df_all['Class'] == classes].unique())
    student_info_temp = student_info_df[student_info_df['Class'] == classes]
    class_groups[classes] = {'class_df': class_df, 'student_info_temp': student_info_temp, 'student_num': student_num}

for group in class_groups.keys():

    student_index = 0
    X_values = [[] for i in range(len(charts_list))]
    Y_values = [[] for i in range(len(charts_list))]
    labels = [[] for i in range(len(charts_list))]
    data_all = [[[]] for j in range(len(charts_list))]

    class_df = class_groups[group]['class_df']
    student_info_temp = class_groups[group]['student_info_temp']
    student_num = class_groups[group]['student_num']

    for chart, chart_index in zip(charts_list, range(0, len(charts_list))):
        if chart == "Future Admission":
            data_all[chart_index][student_index] = [[], [], []]
            X_values[chart_index], data_all[chart_index][student_index][0], data_all[chart_index][student_index][1], data_all[chart_index][student_index][2] = get_activation_data(class_df, date.today())
            data_all[chart_index][student_index] = [[(np.array(data_all[chart_index][student_index][i]) * student_num).tolist() for i in range(len(data_all[chart_index][student_index]))], student_num]
            labels[chart_index] = ['Admission', 'Retention', 'Activation']

        elif chart == "Future Revenue Projection":
            data_all[chart_index][student_index] = [[], []]
            temp_start_date = str((datetime.today()).date())
            X_values[chart_index], data_all[chart_index][student_index][0], data_all[chart_index][student_index][1] = get_revenue_projection(class_df, date.today())
            labels[chart_index] = ['25th Percentile', '50th Percentile', '75th Percentile', 'Median Revenue', '90th Percentile']
        else:
            print("error")
```

Comment: Are you sure you need multiprocessing for that? For example, your first loop can use `groupby`, `agg` or `isin` to improve performance. Loops are not very efficient with Pandas.

Comment: Yes, I need as when I do this computation is only happening for one group at a time and all other group are waiting

Comment: What is the bottleneck? The first or the second loop or the inner loop? You should also provide data and check if all variables are declared (`class_list` for example)

Comment: This looks like it just needs the proper use of Pandas methods, not multiprocessing? (But it's hard to tell without a proper MRE.)

Comment: The dataset has 1M class, running on a 16 core workstation, due to the fact it is running serially it takes alot of time and not utilizing resources.

Comment: Do you mean `class_list` has 1M of classes? What is the size of your dataframe?

Comment: yes! class_list has 1M of classes